# jQuery: highlight nav when div scrolls into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple side navigation of circular divs, clicking on one scrolls you to the relevant `.block` div, this all works just fine. Now though I'm wondering if it's possible to highlight the relevant `.nav-item` div, dependant upon which `.block` div is in view.
e.g. if `#block-3` comes into view, the relevant `.nav-item` div with the `data-hook="3"` will be highlighted `background-color: blue`. 
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rf4Ea/3/ 
HTML:

```
<div id="block-one" class="block"></div>
<div id="block-two" class="block"></div>
<div id="block-three" class="block"></div>
<div id="block-four" class="block"></div>
<div id="block-five" class="block"></div>

<ul class="nav-wrap">
    <li class="nav-item" data-hook="one"></li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-hook="two"></li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-hook="three"></li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-hook="four"></li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-hook="five"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    Resize();
});

//Every resize of window
$(window).resize(function () {
    Resize();
});

//Dynamically assign height
function Resize() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var divwid = $(window).height() / 2,
        navhei = $('.nav-wrap').height() / 2,
        newhei = divwid - navhei;
    $('.nav-wrap').css({
        'top': newhei
    });

}


$('.nav-item').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#block-' + $(this).attr('data-hook')).offset().top - 0
    }, "slow");
});
```

If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"[Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) is a library that makes it easy to execute a function whenever you scroll to an element."_

Sounds like a tool for the problem. Here's how to use the library with jQuery - http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a class selected in your css like that:

```
.nav-item:hover, .nav-item.selected {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

You can bind a function on the scroll event to change the color of the current nav-item:

```
function hoverCurrentItem() {
    var h = $(".block:first").height();
    var sIndex = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / h);
    var $sItem = $(".nav-item").eq(sIndex);
    if (!$sItem.hasClass("selected")) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $sItem.addClass("selected");
    }    
}
hoverCurrentItem();

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    hoverCurrentItem()
});
```

View in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf4Ea/5/)

Comment: I have encountered one small problem with this solution, as `var h` is equal to only the first `.block` div, if all the `.block` divs are different heights (which they will be as the content will be managed via CMS, this solution no longer works. As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/u38VL/1/ Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: I updated you fiddle. This is working at least: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/u38VL/1/ but there's maybe a more elegant solution.

Comment: That seems to be the same link? Can't find the updated fiddle?